# PHP error when uploading large files with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

i ame using XMLHttpRequest to upload file with PHP,
this works fine with small files, but with large files over 15MB, i got this server error:

```
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Broken pipe).**
```

ihave boosted all upload parameters:

```
**upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size 100M
max_input_time 300000
max_execution_time 30000
memory_limit = 200M**
```

but the probleme persists.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you also increased the options in the settings of you webserver? (For nginx it would be `client_max_body_size`)

Comment: I don't use nginx

Answer (score 0):

Your request reaches timeout, not PHP. Increase timeout limit before sending request. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/server', true);

xhr.timeout = 2000; // time in milliseconds

xhr.send(null);
```