# Uploading large videos & Audio files to server using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that has been working perfectly fine when it comes to uploading files and large images. For any image that is too large it gets resized using a canvas and then I append it to the form Data and it saves perfectly. However I have now been asked to allow videos and audio files to be uploaded on the same file input.

This sort of has thrown me for a bit of a loop because even shorter videos from a phone can be 50MB or more especially if the quality of the camera is good. I searched for a number of things but I can't seem to find something that already somewhat works with the submission process I have going on.
I saw I can split the file into chunks and upload it in pieces to the server, but the other unfortunate part is when I submit the file (image, pdf, mp4, mp3) I am also submitting other information, like Description (small paragraph describing the file), name of person submitting the file etc.

**My current process goes a little something like this:**
Person uploads file + information, I send it away using `formData` and  `new XMLHttpRequest()`.
On the server side I  get the name, set the path and get a date for the submission. The name of the image/file gets changed to be something like `20200128200812_imageName.jpeg` which helps me retrieve the image based on what time the form was submitted (database column frmSubmitted).

**What I am attempting to do:**
Allow a user submit a form with the ability to process video types and audio types but still process the information that is associated with the file, like name or description.

I'm afraid if I submit the video or audio file in chunks, I will be also submitting the other information as well, I might be wrong on this but all other posts I have read seem to mention making separate requests might be the only way to do this. The following code works and is how I am currently set up but I am including it for context.

```
html
<input type="text" id="name"/>
<textarea id="description" name="description" rows="5" cols="50" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
<input type="file" name="sFile" id="sFile"  multiple />
<button onclick="submitFile();" class="btn" >submit</button>

JS
 function submitFile(){
const files= document.querySelector('#sFile').files;
        var formData = new FormData();
        if (files.length > 0){
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file= files[i];
                if(checkFileExtension(file)  && checkFileSize(file)){ //checks the file for images and the size of the image
                    image = resizeImage(file);
                    formData.append('images[]', image);
                }else{
                  formData.append(file[], file);
                }
            }
        }
/*
*getting values & error handling...
*/
        //appending values
        formData.append('desc', description);
        formData.append('personName', name);

var postrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    postrequest.open('post', 'include/fileProcessing.php', true);
    postrequest.send(formData);
         postrequest.onload = function(){
             var data = JSON.parse(postrequest.responseText);
             if(data.result == 'true' ){
                alert('Form has been submitted!');
}

php
$date = date('YmdHis');
if (isset($_FILES['images'])) {
        $errors = [];
        $path = '../images/uploads/'; 
        $extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf'];

        $all_files = count($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $all_files; $i++) {
            $original_Name = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];
            $file_name =  $date .'_'.$original_Name;
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $file_type = $_FILES['images']['type'][$i];
            $file_size = $_FILES['images']['size'][$i]/1024;
            $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['images']['name'][$i])));

            if (!in_array($file_ext, $extensions)) {
                $errors[] = 'Image type not allowed: ' . $original_Name . ' ' . $file_type;
            }

            if ($file_size > 2097152) {
                $errors = 'Image size too large';
            }

            $file = $path . $file_name;
            if (empty($errors)) {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file);
            }
        }
        if ($errors) $rtVariables['picErrors'] = $errors;
    }
/**check and upload files that are not images but too long to post**/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need to break it up into chunks? Your web-server and web-client/browser should both support `mutlipart/form-data`. Also, you're using `FormData.append` incorrectly.. I don't know why you're passing `file[]` in as a **name** (string; not sure why you're not getting an error from this if you aren't); each file needs to be named differently or else you will have problems receiving all the files on the server.

Comment: Also, what **exactly** is your question? Based on the way you have this set up, it should work just like it does for other file-types, have you actually attempted uploading a video the same way you upload images to see what happens on your server? If not, you're thinking way way ahead of yourself. You first need to determine if your server **can't** do what you're trying to do before you should look into changing how the request is received.

Comment: Sorry but I dont see audio or videos allowed to upload `$extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf'];` If its a question then its asked before : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740146/php-error-when-uploading-large-files-with-xmlhttprequest?rq=1